# Custom Syntax Highlighting in ICSharp.texteditor

Tags: .net, vb.net, icsharpcode

I am trying to make an IDE of the language PAWN.

I am using the ICSharp in C# for Syntax Highlighting. Since PAWN is not already there in scintilla, can someone tell me how to create custom syntax highlighting?

Here are the keywords

> assert char #assert const break defined #defined enum case sizeof #else forward continue state #elseif native default tagof #emit new do #endif operator else #endinput public exit #endscript static for #error stock goto #file if #if return #include sleep #line state #pragma switch #section while #tryinclude #undef

Answer (score 1):

You should first check if jEdit supports that language,

http://www.lextm.com/2012/01/tritonmate-words-syntax-highlighting-for-smimib/

If jEdit supports it, you can easily convert the jEdit grammar file to the style SharpDevelop TextEditor expects.

If there is none in jEdit, it is not too hard to write your own according to

https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/Syntax-highlighting